# Mach3 Mill reversing

Tags: c#, multithreading, lpt

I'm trying to write a program like Mach3Mill that controls LPT servos. Now I use C# and library [inpout32.dll](http://www.highrez.co.uk/Downloads/InpOut32/) to send data to LPT. The main problem is to make moving smooth like the original program does.

Now I'm sending data in loop changing data bit from 1 to 0 with intervals using Thread.SpinWait because Thread.Sleep produces larger intervals.

Are there any ways to send data with selected frequency?

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: Windows isn't a real time operating system, but you can get close to what you're looking for.  You could probably use a timer, do a search for "Real Time Timers".   What kind of accuracy are you looking for?

Comment: Windows is not a realtime operating system, so the typical solution for CNCs is to delegate this to a hardware motion controller. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/44631/writing-to-parallel-port-with-minimum-latency and http://blog.cnccookbook.com/2011/12/23/motion-control-boards-take-mach3-from-hobby-class-to-industrial-grade-part-1/ for elaboration. Setting your thread to the highest possible priority may help, but `SpinWait` should be a tight loop, so you may not do much better. If you can show us what you've done, and what your goal is, someone might be able to help.

Comment: What kind of time granularity do you need? 50ms, 250ms?

Comment: Thanks to everybody, yes windows is not RTOS and I'm quite discouraged because this device(default with cutter) relies only on Mach3Mill performance. I'll record a short video next Monday how it works, and now I started to think about replacing original controller which actions like useless transport between PC and servos(actually can't use G-codes)...

Comment: Found out that there's "BUSY FLAG", will check it also.